Cannot boot ubuntu after replacing the windows partitions of my dual boot pc by a data partition
I have recently chosen to completely delete my windows installation and only use Ubuntu.
I have deleted all the partitions related to windows and created a new one with gpart. I then mounted this data partition from the terminal.
Since then, I cannot boot with Ubuntu. The bootloader is working, but has still windows in it, which just gives me a blue error.
When I click Ubuntu, there is the booting logo and animation, and then a few lines of errors :
5.8659081 usbhid 3-4:1.2: couldn't find an input interrupt endpoint /dev/numeon1p4: clean, 658378/21389312 files, 81271215/85545216 blocks 6.9685821 kum_and: SUM disabled (by BIOS) in MSR_VM_CR on CPU 5 7.2609681 snd_hda_intel 0000:08:00.0: Unknown capability 0

E 36.372958] usbhid 3-4:1.2: couldn't find an input interrupt endpoint

I have no idea of how to fix this, so if anyone can help, I would be very grateful.

The following was posted by OP as answers:
I also noticed that my new data partition is not shown in the recovery menu, and, my main Ubuntu partition appears to be full, which is not the case. Maybe an unfinished heavy download ?
Here is more information, without the quiet option :
image link
It appears that GNOME couldn't start.
Using systemctl status gdm.service :
gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager
    Loaded: loaded (/lib/.../gdm.service;static)
    Active: inactive (dead)


I also noticed that my new data partition is not shown in the recovery menu, and, my main Ubuntu partition appears to be full, which is not the case.
Maybe an unfinished heavy download ?

Here is more information, without the quiet option :
image link
It appears that GNOME couldn't start.
Using systemctl status gdm.service :
gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager
    Loaded: loaded (/lib/.../gdm.service;static)
    Active: inactive (dead)


none of these errors look like something that would stop a boot. Try booting without the quiet option (edit the kernel parameters in the bootloader) to get more output.

Can you boot recovery mode, second in grub menu. If one install, you probably have to press Escape key just after UEFI/BIOS screen, but before grub menu normally appears. And do you have Windows partitions mounting with fstab. That should not stop boot, but you may have to wait for time out.

usbhid=USB Human Interface Device.
This error can happen when a mouse or keyboard aren't recognized by Linux. Try a different mouse and/or keyboard and see if it gets past that error.
Or you could try this, found as an answer on a thread in Stack Exchange by Steven Rauch:
Go to bios, usb configuration,
USB debugging must be disabled
Save and Exit.
Problem Solved.
